# Cypress - addContext() is keeping previous failure count and adding it to each 'it' scenario in mochawesome report

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, mochawesome

In my mochawesome-report `addContext()` is keeping previous count and adding it to each 'it' scenario, in case of a test case failure, I'm adding 'someValue' as context to the test case. So if 2nd test case fails then value is getting printed twice.

Following is the snapshot:

[image]

Following is my `afterEach()` method :

```
afterEach(function () {
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {    
      var test = this.currentTest

      Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test) => {

        addContext({ test }, {
          title: 'Failing Screenshot: ' + '>> screenshots/' + Cypress.spec.name + '/' + test_name + ' -- ' + test.title + ' (failed)' + '.png <<',
          value: 'screenshots/' + Cypress.spec.name + '/' + test_name + ' -- ' + test.title + ' (failed)' + '.png'
          //value: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA+gAAABkCAYAAAAVORraAAACH0lEQVR'
        })
      });
    } 
  })
```

Comment: Why are you mixing Cypress.on with an afterEach hook? You really want to add a new event listener on every test?

Comment: YES, you are right, I've changed that in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got what I was looking from https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Cypress-Events

[image]

Though I'll have to remove  `Cypress.on('test:after:run',`  `afterEach()`

So I'll have to specify `Cypress.on('test:after:run',` in each spec file

```
const spec_name = this.title

  Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test) => {

    if (test.state === 'failed') {
      addContext({ test }, {
        title: 'Failing Screenshot: ' + '>> screenshots/' + Cypress.spec.name + '/' + spec_name + ' -- ' + test.title + ' (failed)' + '.png <<',
        value: 'screenshots/' + Cypress.spec.name + '/' + spec_name + ' -- ' + test.title + ' (failed)' + '.png'
      })
    }
  });
```

which is kind of put off, it would be better to put this whole code in `support/command.js`

Comment: Why can't you put that in `support/index.js`?

Comment: I need to have current spec title and current test title to be passed to cypress.on, feel free to share how to do that

Comment: Do you know how to get the current spec title yet?

Comment: I found it. `runnable.parent.title`. Just add `runnable` like this`Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {`

Comment: Thanks Jake, I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code :

```
const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');

Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
  if (test.state === 'failed') {
    addContext({test}, { title: "Screenshot", value:`../cypress/screenshots/${Cypress.spec.name}/${runnable.parent.title} -- ${test.title} (failed).png` })
  }
})
```

inside "support/index.js" and you will have the screenshot of the failed test within your reports

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround if you need to use it within tests (using test id)

In your `support/index.js`

```js
Cypress.on('test:before:run', (test, runnable) => {
  if (!window['extra']) {
    window['extra'] = []
  }

  if (!window['extra'][test.id]) {
    window['extra'][test.id] = []
  }
})

Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
    window['extra'][test.id].map((item) => {
      addContext({ test }, item)
    })
})
```

And now you can use it within your test (getting the test.id)

```js
it('some test', function() {
  // Using window to bypass issue with context
        window['extra'][this.test.id].push( {
          title: 'Hello',
          value: 'World
        })  
})
```